# POI cell colour and width

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

trying to write to work book and change the cell colour using...

```
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_FILL);

    for (int i = 0; i < headerTitles.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(headerTitles[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
```

However it seems to output the colour with just a foreground of grey dots and I cant seem to work out why.

Secondly what is the method to set the width of a cell automatically, or even the first 5 columns of a work book.

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the second question, use this method:

```
void org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(int column)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, i also realised that the answer to the first is to use foreground colour and not BG!